# Spring @RequestBody containing a list of different types (but same interface)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say that I have a domain class :

```
    public class Zoo{
        private List<Animal> animals;
        ....
```

where an Animal is an interface with different implementations (Cat,Dog). Let's say that I want to be able to save a Zoo object :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/zoo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void save(@RequestBody Zoo zoo) {
    ....
```

and I want to send a json - something like :

```
    {
        animals:[
            {type:'Cat', whiskers-length:'3'},
            {type:'Dog', name:'Fancy'}
        ]
    }
```

How can I tell spring MVC to map animal to Cat type when type=='Cat' and to map it to a Dog class when type=='Dog'?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with invalid json. But still it doesn't solve my problem, which is the mapping from the json object {type:'Cat', whiskersLength:'3'} to Cat class. Zoo class only know that the animals list contains animals. But how do the json deserializer know which implementation of Animal interface (Dog or Cat) to use for specific json object?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use the Jackson annotations [`@JsonTypeInfo`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html) and [`@JsonSubTypes`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonSubTypes.html) to achieve polymorphic json.  The annotations go on the `Animal` base class.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat")})
public abstract class Animal {

}
```

Comment: This looks great for 2 subtypes (Cats and Dogs), but what if you have a huge list of subtypes? There are more types of animals in a zoo :)

Comment: is it any way to put some annotation on Cat or Dog, without putting `@JsonSubTypes` on animal?

Comment: don't forget about visible = true in case you don't want to lose property "type" inside json, @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)

Answer (score 7):

There is a simpler annotation out now:

```
@JsonRootName("dog")
public class Dog extends Animal {...}
```

The reference to the annotation can be found on [fasterxml.github](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html)