# Spring @ReponseBody @RequestBody with abstract class

Tags: json, spring, jackson, abstract-class

Suppose I have three classes.

```
public abstract class Animal {}

public class Cat extends Animal {}

public class Dog extends Animal {}
```

Can I do something like this?

Input: a JSON which it is Dog or Cat

Output: a dog/cat depends on input object type

I don't understand why the following code doesn't work. Or should I use two separate methods to handle new dog and cat?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/animal", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
private @ResponseBody <T extends Animal>T insertAnimal(@RequestBody T animal) {
    return animal;
}
```

Error message:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type variable 'T' can not be
> resolved

Comment: What do you mean with "code doesnt work." Runtime error? Compiler error? Where is the error log? You have to help us to understand the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit late, but I think you should accept your own answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @RequestBody containing a list of different types (but same interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247189/spring-requestbody-containing-a-list-of-different-types-but-same-interface)

Answer (score 63):

[ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247189/spring-requestbody-containing-a-list-of-different-types-but-same-interface)

I just found the answer myself and here is the reference link.

What I have done is added some code above the abstract class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.*;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog")
})
public abstract class Animal{}
```

Then in the json input in HTML,

```
var inputjson = {
    "type":"cat",
    //blablabla
};
```

After submitting the json and finally in the controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/animal", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody insertanimal(@RequestBody Animal tmp) {
    return tmp;
}
```

In this case variable tmp is automatically converted to a `Dog` or `Cat` object, depending on json input.

Comment: is it any way to put some annotation on Cat or Dog, without putting `@JsonSubTypes` on animal?

Comment: What is the best practice for this ?

Comment: For the record, as specified in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611199/jackson-jsontypeinfo-property-is-being-mapped-as-null if you want the property to be mapped in the request object, use `visible = true`